Count all unique triples
Suppose that I have a pandas data frame A with columns called user_id and history where history is an array of ints. And the possible histories are bounded from above by 2000. I need to iterate through all rows of A, for each history b = [b1, b2, b3, ..., bn]. All bi's are unique(only appearing once in the array). I need to find all possible triples (bi, bj, bk) such that i < j < k, and count the occurrences of all such triples. In addition, we treat the triple (bi, bj, bk) to be the same as (bj, bi, bk) if bi > bj.
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

# Example DataFrame A (replace this with your actual DataFrame)
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# Example DataFrame A (replace this with your actual DataFrame)
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3],
    'history': [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
})

# Initialize a dictionary to store counts of triples
triple_counts = defaultdict(int)

# Iterate over each row of A
for index, row in A.iterrows():
    history = row['history']
    n = len(history)

    
    # Iterate over all triples (bi, bj, bk) where i < j < k
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            for k in range(j + 1, n):
                bi = history[i]
                bj = history[j]
                bk = history[k]
                
                if bi < bj:
                    triple_counts[(bi, bj, bk)] += 1
                else:
                    triple_counts[(bj, bi, bk)] += 1

# Output the counts of all triples
for triple, count in triple_counts.items():
    print(f"Triple {triple}: Count = {count}")

The issue with this approach is that A is an extremely large data frame and each row has a complexity of O(n^3) so it takes forever to complete this computation. Is there faster way to do this possibly leveraging pytorch or tensor operations?

Can only the first two items of the triples be switched while keeping equality or can all items be permutated so that the triples actually can be treated as sets?

It only applies to the first two items.

Have the history lists of all rows the same length? Is there a know maximum for the value of all bi's (so that they can be stored in a usual machine datatype like e. g. int64)?

They are variable length and the bi's range from 0 to 2000

I understand your problem as "each history array have elements with values of 0 - 2000, all unique". If so, you will be dealing with COMBIN(2001, 3) = 1.3 billion combinations. It's a huge number of loops!

Do you even have enough time to read a billion results? And won't you get bored real quick?

One way which may make it a bit faster (hard to guess with your small sample)  is to work hierarchically with a dictionary using the first two items of the triple as key (after they were sorted) and a Counter as value which collects the counts of the last item of the triple:
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

# Example DataFrame A (replace this with your actual DataFrame)
A = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3],
    'history': [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
})

# Initialize a dictionary to store counters of pairs
hierarchic_counts = defaultdict(Counter)

# Iterate over history column of A. This is definitely faster than iterating
#   over the rows of A
for history in A['history']:
    n = len(history)

    # Iterate over pairs with i < j
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            bi = history[i]
            bj = history[j]
            if bi < bj:
                key = (bi, bj)
            else:
                key = (bj, bi)

            hierarchic_counts[key].update(history[j + 1:])

# Convert to original triple counts
triple_counts = {}
for key, counter in hierarchic_counts.items():
    for third, count in counter.items():
        triple_counts[key + (third,)] = count

# Output the counts of all triples
for triple, count in triple_counts.items():
    print(f"Triple {triple}: Count = {count}")


Method 1 : Using Torch  and Numpy
import pandas as pd
import torch
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'datas': [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
})

# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
datas = [torch.tensor(d) for d in df['datas']]

# Initialize triplet count dictionary
triplet_count_dict = defaultdict(int)

for d in datas:
    if len(d) < 3:
        continue
    
    n = len(d)
    #torch.combinations are not efficient for Huge datasets.
    #idx_combinations = torch.combinations(input = idx, r =3)
    #Generate Efficiently all combinations of indices (i, j, k) where i < j < k
    idx_combinations = np.array([[i, j, k] for i in range(n-2) 
                                for j in range(i+1, n-1) for k in range(j+1, n)])
    
    # Convert numpy combinations to PyTorch tensor
    idx_combinations = torch.tensor(idx_combinations)
    
    # Extract the corresponding elements for these indices
    triplets = d[idx_combinations]
    
    # Normalize the triplets so that bi < bj 
    bi = triplets[:, 0]
    bj = triplets[:, 1]
    bk = triplets[:, 2]
    
    # Swap bi and bj to ensure bi <= bj
    mask = bi > bj
    bi[mask], bj[mask] = bj[mask], bi[mask]
    
    # Count the occurrences of each triplet
    for t in torch.stack((bi, bj, bk), dim=1):
        triplet_count_dict[tuple(t.tolist())] += 1

# Print the triplet count dictionary
print(triplet_count_dict)

# Print triplets and their counts
for k, v in triplet_count_dict.items():
    print(f"Triplet {k}: Count = {v}")

'''
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(1, 2, 3): 1, (2, 3, 4): 1, (1, 3, 5): 1})
Triplet (1, 2, 3): Count = 1
Triplet (2, 3, 4): Count = 1
Triplet (1, 3, 5): Count = 1
'''

Method 2 :  Using pure Numpy
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

# Create a pandas DataFrame with sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'datas': [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5]]
})

# Convert data sequences from lists to NumPy arrays for efficient processing
datas = [np.array(d) for d in df['datas']]

# Initialize a dictionary to store triplet counts with default value 0
triplet_count_dict = defaultdict(int)

# Loop through each data sequence in the list 'datas'
for d in datas:

    # Get the length (number of elements) of the current data sequence
    n = len(d)

    # Skip sequences with less than 3 elements (not enough for triplets)
    if len(d) < 3:
        continue

    # Generate all combinations of indices (i, j, k) where i < j < k
    # This is explained in detail below
    idx_combinations = np.array([[i, j, k] for i in range(n-2)
                                 for j in range(i+1, n-1) for k in range(j+1, n)])

    # Extract the corresponding elements from the data sequence based on the combinations
    triplets = d[idx_combinations]

    # Separate the elements of each triplet (i.e., columns of the array)
    bi = triplets[:, 0]  # First element
    bj = triplets[:, 1]  # Second element
    bk = triplets[:, 2]  # Third element

    # Normalize the triplets so that the first element (bi) is always less than the second (bj)
    mask = bi > bj
    bi[mask], bj[mask] = bj[mask], bi[mask]  # Swap elements if necessary

    # Loop through each normalized triplet
    for t in np.stack((bi, bj, bk), axis=1):
        # Convert the triplet to a tuple (hashable for dictionary key) and increment its count
        triplet_count_dict[tuple(t)] += 1

# Print the dictionary containing the counts of each unique triplet
print(triplet_count_dict)
'''
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {(1, 2, 3): 1, (2, 3, 4): 1, (1, 3, 5): 1})
'''
# Print the triplets and their corresponding counts in a more readable format
for k, v in triplet_count_dict.items():
    print(f"Triplet {k}: Count = {v}")
    
    
'''
Triplet (1, 2, 3): Count = 1
Triplet (2, 3, 4): Count = 1
Triplet (1, 3, 5): Count = 1
'''


You don't need to loop over all combinations. just transform your lists to frozenset and count with collections.Counter:
from collections import Counter

Counter(map(frozenset, A['history']))

Output:
Counter({frozenset({1, 2, 3}): 1,
         frozenset({2, 3, 4}): 1,
         frozenset({1, 3, 5}): 1})

or sort and convert to tuples:
from collections import Counter

Counter(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in A['history'])

Output:
Counter({(1, 2, 3): 1,
         (2, 3, 4): 1,
         (1, 3, 5): 1})

This will run in O(n).
Note that you could also use value_counts:
A['history'].map(frozenset).value_counts()

history
(1, 2, 3)    1
(2, 3, 4)    1
(1, 3, 5)    1
Name: count, dtype: int64

A['history'].map(sorted).value_counts()

history
[1, 2, 3]    1
[2, 3, 4]    1
[1, 3, 5]    1
Name: count, dtype: int64


Thanks for the answer! The arrays are not necessarily of three elements though.

@Adam can you clarify? This approach doesn't require the arrays to have a specific number of elements. Can you please update your example and the matching expected output?

If you want to consider subsets triplets out of larger inputs, then you have to loop over the combinations. Your code could be simplified to Counter(c for x in A['history'] for c in combinations(sorted(x), 3))` since you defined "(bi, bj, bk) such that i < j < k". Again, crafting a meaningful example would improve clarity.
